# Determining which octant has a specific point

Tags: python, algorithm, coordinate-system

I am interested in [octants in plane geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octant_%28plane_geometry%29), which basically involves dividing a plane into 8 equal parts according to a certain point.

[image: Octants]

Octants are particularly useful while implementing [the Bresenham's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm).

### Problem

Given two points `A = (x1, y1)` and `B = (x2, y2)`, how to determine in which octant belongs B according to A?

Counting octants is performed as shown: starting from the upper right and iterating anticlockwise.

### Naive implementation

```
def get_octant(pA, pB):
    AX = pA[0]
    AY = pA[1]
    BX = pB[0]
    BY = pB[1]

    if BX > AX:
        if BY > AY:
            if (BY - AY) < (BX - AX):
                octant = 0
            else:
                octant = 1
        else:
            if (AY - BY) < (BX - AX):
                octant = 7
            else:
                octant = 6
    else:
        if BY > AY:
            if (BY - AY) < (AX - BX):
                octant = 3
            else:
                octant = 2
        else:
            if (AY - BY) < (AX - BX):
                octant = 4
            else:
                octant = 5

    return octant
```

Would it not possible to find a cleverer implementation?

Using the symmetry properties, I am convinced that it is possible to make a shorter and more readable code. Unfortunately, I do not find it myself, so does anyone have an idea, please?

Comment: Unrelated: to support `A.x` syntax, you could use [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html)

Comment: A small suggestion: rather than assigning `Ax`, `Ay`, ... on individual lines, consider using tuples unpacking: `Ax, Ay = pA; Bx, By = pB`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I am convinced that it is possible to make a shorter and more readable code.

To implement the discrete analog of `atan2((B.y - A.y), (B.x - A.x))`:

```
x, y  = (B.x - A.x), (B.y - A.y)
octant = [([1, 2], [8, 7]), ([4, 3], [5, 6])][x < 0][y < 0][abs(x) < abs(y)]
```

It is shorter, I don't know about readability. It is easy to write tests that check all possible variants including the behavior on the boundaries.

Comment: For readability, you could add `octant_labels = [([1, 2], [8, 7]), ([4, 3], [5, 6])]` and then write `octant = octant_labels[x < 0][y < 0][abs(x) < abs(y)]`

Answer (score 4):

You can look at the computation of the octant number (q) of [a paper that I co-authored](http://dx.doi.org/10.5194/isprsarchives-XL-5-145-2014):

```
import numpy as np

T = np.rad2deg(np.arctan2(Y,X))

if T < 0:
    T += 360

q = np.ceil(T/45)

print q
```

… where X = x2 - x1; Y = y2 - y1

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are exploitable symmetries.

```
def get_octant(pA, pB):
    dx, dy = pB[0] - pA[0], pB[1] - pA[1]
    octant = 0
    if dy < 0:
        dx, dy = -dx, -dy  # rotate by 180 degrees
        octant += 4
    if dx < 0:
        dx, dy = dy, -dx  # rotate clockwise by 90 degrees
        octant += 2
    if dx < dy:
        # no need to rotate now
        octant += 1
    return octant
```

Comment: (This doesn't have the same behavior as your code on octant boundaries. It's not clear whether this is an issue.)

Comment: you beat me to it, as often happens. =) However my solution was slightly less obvious as to why it worked, and slightly more code. +1

Answer (score 3):

I would go with finding the angle between `AB` and a line parallel to the `oX` axis. You can simulate the line parallel to `oX` that passes through `A` with `AC` where `C(A.x+k,A.y)` (for any `k>0`). Now, since `ABC` forms a triangle, you can exploit the [cosine law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines), hence the angle `<BAC` being `acos((AB^2 + AC^2 - BC^2)/(2*AB*AC))` this will give you an angle in the range `[0,pi]`. In order to adjust it, you would like to know whether `B` is above or below `AC`. This can be computed with `sign(B.y - A.y)` which gives `1` if `B` is above and `-1` otherwise.

Putting it all together:  `((-180*(sign(B.y - A.y)-1) + acos((AB^2 + AC^2 - BC^2)/(2*AB*AC)) * sign(B.y - A.y)) div 45)+1`. This will give exactly the values from your image.

However, this doesn't mean that this one liner will execute faster then the nested if/else you have, reason for this: implementation of `acos()` is non trivial; no optimisations e.g. branch prediction.

Comment: This is the math I was looking for, thank you! I accepted Sebastian's answer as it is more understandable and probably faster, but yours is what I had in mind while publishing this question.